# No other homegroup PCs are available right now

Tags: windows-10, homegroup

We have setup a Homegroup on `Computer1` and are trying to join it with `Computer2`.

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Control Panel > Network and Internet > HomeGroup.
2. Click Join now.
3. In the Join a Homegroup Wizard, type the password.
4. Click Next then Finish.
5. Close the Control Panel and open File Explorer.
6. In the Navigation Panel, click Homegroup.
7. Wait about 1 minute while a "Working on it..." message displays.
8. See the following message:

#### No other homegroup PCs are available right now.

Make sure that:

- The other homegroup PCs are awake and connected to the network.
- All the PCs in your homegroup have sharing turned on.
- The other homegroup PCs have the current homegroup password.
- Other people in your homegroup are sharing libraries with the homegroup.

We have made sure that all of the above criteria are true.

Answer (score 1):

## The Fix

Create a brand new homegroup, because the existing one was corrupted.

## Steps

On **both** computers:

1. Leave the homegroup.
2. Delete everything inside `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking`.
3. Turn off the computer.

Now that both computers are off:

1. Turn on **one** computer.
2. Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Homegroup.
3. Click the "Create a homegroup" button and follow the steps.

[image: Create a homegroup]

Now that you have a new homegroup:

1. Turn on the second computer.
2. Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Homegroup.
3. Click the "Join now" button and follow the steps.

[image: Join now]

## Notes

- If you do not see the "Create a homegroup" button, then this process is not working and you will need to try something else.
- This process also works to delete (and recreate) a homegroup that contains computers that you no longer have.